# Keycloak email custom theme, get user ID

Tags: keycloak

I'm creating a custom theme to emails on keycloak and I need to get the user Id who ask for password reset. I can get the Username, the Firs name etc by user.getUsername(),user.getFirstName() but I can't get the Id. I tried user.getUserId, user.getId, user.getID..but always get an error. Can anybody helps me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the id is not available out of the box. The `user` attribute is an instance of [`ProfileBean`](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/beans/ProfileBean.html). You can only use the properties of that class.

You will need to either find a way to map it into an attribute or write a custom [EmailTemplateProvider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/email/EmailTemplateProvider.html)